# SwiftUI complicated view using geometry reader

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am working on a complicated UI that I keep encountering issue when I try to make it. First, this is my current code:

```
var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                if showNewBadge {
                    NewBadge(title: "NEW")
                }
                Text("jfsdbf hjksdb fhjkdsb ")
                    .dynamicFont(.Cloud9.paragraph)
                    .lineLimit(2)
                if let subtext {
                    Text("djfb dsjhbf jsdhk fbjsdhk fbjdshkf bjs")
                        .dynamicFont(.Cloud9.caption)
                        .lineLimit(3)
                }
                if let parterLogoUrl {
                    KFImage(parterLogoUrl)
                        .useHatchFade()
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 65, height: 20)
                        .clipped()
                }
                if showCTA {
                    Button(action: tapOnCTAAction, label: {
                        Label("Listen Now", systemImage: "play")
                    })
                    .buttonStyle(.outlineSmall)
                }
            }
            .padding(.leading)
            if let parterLogoUrl {
                KFImage.url(parterLogoUrl)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .overlay(
                        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.black.opacity(0.5), Color.clear]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
                    )
            }
            
        }
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: .cornerRadiusDefault)
                .foregroundColor(.blue))
    }
```

Now i will explain what the issues are and what I want to achieve.
So first problem is, in the image that is on the right side of the HStack, I want it to take the whole height of the container and half the width of it's container. I tried using geometry reader, but it made the gradient go beyond the bounds. If someone knows how to make it work with geometry reader, I would appreciate it.
Second is, I am trying to make the image slowly blend as it moves to the left towards the center, with the background color. By blending, I mean it can fade away slowly so we only start seeing the background color after we reach the center.

The end goal is having a card, that on the right half has an image, and the left half has some information. The image slowly fades away as we move towards the center. The info and image each take half the width of the card. If my approach is not ideal, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aspect ratio of your image is throwing things off. If you set the width of your HStack and the image to half the geometry reader, that balances things out. When you resize the container and the image ratio becomes troublesome, it centers the image in its container leaving blank space on the left and right. The easiest thing to do is `.fill` your image instead of `.fit`.

If you need the image to use `.fit`, then I'd suggest giving your HStack a fixed height that works for you.

To blend your gradient, simply set the first color in the gradient to your background color to match.

```
        GeometryReader { geo in
        HStack {
            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                if showNewBadge {
                    NewBadge(title: "NEW")
                }
                Text("jfsdbf hjksdb fhjkdsb ")
                    .lineLimit(2)
                Text("djfb dsjhbf jsdhk fbjsdhk fbjdshkf bjs")
                    .lineLimit(3)
                Text("@") // logo
                Button("Listen Now") {
                    print("some action")
                }
            }
            .padding(.leading)
            .frame(width: geo.size.width / 2) // set width, not height.
            
            HStack {
                Spacer() // when the radio mixes things up...push to end
                Image("demos")
                    .resizable()
                //                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit) // <- the aspect ratio is whats making it difficult to calculate.
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .overlay(
                        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color.clear]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
                    )
                // set width, not height.
            }.frame(width: geo.size.width / 2)
            
        }
        // fixed height here
        .background(.blue)
        .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)) // rounds off image too!
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I actually prefer to use .fill but when I do, the card takes over the whole screen. Even right now when I copied and pasted your code, the same issue happened with .fill and the whole screen becomes the background color.

Comment: What about setting the HStack height to half the width? That way the image will be square and might prevent it from exploding. .frame(height: geo.size.width / 2)

Comment: That fixes that problem, thank you!